# Plants taxonomy: priority of names published in the same year

Tags: botany, taxonomy

Article 11.3 of the International Code of Nomenclature for algae, fungi, and plants states that the earliest valid name with the same rank has the priority.

The question is: if two names (or more...) of the same species have been validly published exactly in the same year and, apparently, it seems impossible to ascertain which one was published earlier, how to decide which one is the name which has the priority?

Thanks

Comment: Is this a hypothetical? Because I can't see this actually happening unless it's a new species identified separately by two individuals unaware of the other's discovery.

Comment: Not hypothetical. It is something that happens.
It is a case of two binomials (referring to two distinct plants) but that are exactly homonymous and have been published exactly in the same year. So, I have the need to decide if one or another has the priority.
Unfortunately old works did not show the month of publication, so at the moment I cannot uscertain which one was published earlier in that year.

Comment: As you state, it's not just the year but any point earlier in time. Even though the publications may not indicate themselves exactly when they were published, I think this still holds. I know there are cases where folks have done a lot of extra research to establish when, or likely when, certain manuscripts were published in order to clear up questions like this.

Comment: @David, nomenclature is essential for talking about anything in biology, and the taxonomists who craft the various Codes are working biologists, so they may indeed frequent this site and know the answer. It's true that this question isn't about biological processes, but this site is "for biology researchers, academics, and students," and specifically covers "questions about techniques in a biological or biochemical laboratory," which I think pretty squarely includes taxonomic techniques.

Comment: @Darlingtonia - I could not agree more that this question, though it may not have an answer, belongs on this site. To the OP, is it possible to contact the publisher(s) for the date of publication? If you must write about it, you can give both names. For a good while after orexin/hypocretin was discovered by two separate groups pretty much simultaneously, it was referred to as "orexin/hypocretin". Now it's usually referred to as "[one], also known as [the other]". I have no idea when this will be resolved.

Comment: Please supply details of the case and provide a link to the International Code of Nomenclature.